# Is it possible to make an if statement if a list item is equal to a certain number in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I've been working on a truth or dare app, in which you spin a wheel and you randomly get a truth or dare, and I want to have a bunch of random truth questions and dares saved in a `database`.

I have it set up so when you press the spin `button` it randomly chooses a truth or dare out of an `array`. 
i've tried it a little and couldn't seem to get it to work. so my question is would it be possible to do something like, 
`if self.number[0] == 0 || 2 || 3{ (this is where it would get the random truth)}`
`else{(this is where it would get the random dare)}`

I don't know if it will help, but this is the rest of my code.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreHaptics



class Colors{
    static var drinkGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("drinkcard"), Color("drinkcard2"), Color("drinkcard")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)]
    static var truthGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("truthcard"), Color("truthcard"), Color("truthcard")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)]
    static var dareGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("darecard"), Color("darecard"), Color("darecard")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)]
}

struct ContentView: View {



    @State private var timer:Timer!
    @State private var text = [String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Drink!!")]
    @State private var foregrounds = [Color.white, Color.white, Color.white, Color.white, Color.white, Color.white, Color.black]
    @State private var number = [0]
    @State private var timeKeeper: Float = 0
    @State private var angle: Double = 0
    let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
    @State var backgrounds = [Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.drinkGradient[0]]
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color("background"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Text("Truth, Dare or Drink")
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded) )
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 100)
                        .background(Color("banner"))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                        .shadow(radius: 15)
                }


                Text("This is where the Truth or dare will go.")
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))

                Spacer()

                Text(text[number[0]])
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(foregrounds[number[0]])
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .background(backgrounds[number[0]])
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
                    .animation(.easeIn)

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.10, repeats: true, block: {_ in

                        self.timeKeeper += 0.10
                        if self.timeKeeper < 3{
                            if self.number[0] == self.text.count - 1{
                                self.number[0] = 0
                                self.angle += 360
                                let impactHeavy = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                                impactHeavy.impactOccurred()
                            }
                            else{
                                self.number[0] += 1
                                self.angle += 360
                                let impactHeavy = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                                impactHeavy.impactOccurred()
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            self.number[0] = Int.random(in:
                                0...self.text.count - 1)
                            let impactHeavy = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                            impactHeavy.impactOccurred()
                            self.angle += 360
                            self.timeKeeper = 0
                            self.timer.invalidate()
                        }
                    })
                }) {
                    Text("Spin")
                        .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                        .background(Color("button"))
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                        .shadow(radius: 15)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `self.number` being an array of just one element, namely zero? Why is it an array, and why would it ever be anything other than one element which is zero? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (self.number[0] == 0 || self.number[0] == 2 || self.number[0] == 3) {
   print("truth")
} else {
   print("dare")
}
```